# Should I repost a revised version of a really old, closed challenge?

Tags: discussion, editing, closed-questions, reposting

I found an interesting, closed challenge. I know that I can address the flaws that led it to closure. Normally, I would edit the challenge into shape, but the question is over a year old and I want it to get the attention is deserves.

Should I repost it?

Comment: Giving us more insight into the original challenge may help us determine whether it's salvagable...

Comment: @TheDoctor The question is salvageable. Please read "I know that I can address the flaws that led it to closure." in the question.

Answer (score 9):

I think this can go either way, and it depends mainly on the original question.

If it was so flawed that there isn't an easy way to edit it into shape, then I don't see a problem with reposting.

If the fix is something relatively minor, I'd prefer to see it edited into shape and reopened, since I feel that's one of the basic tenets of Stack Exchange. The whole reason we *have* edit privileges is to make things better over time.

Of course, "major" and "minor" fixes are subjective, and I can see where people might disagree with which category a particular question falls into. In this case just choose one or the other and the votes/community will sort it out.

---

I don't believe that "it should get more attention" is a valid reason for posting a duplicate, and has no bearing here. The usual methods for gathering more attention to a question (bounties, chat, social media, whatever) can be used in this case.

Comment: Also note that editing and reopening a question will bump it to the top of the homepage, where active questions are listed.