# Closing old questions as duplicates in favour of new ones

Tags: discussion, duplicates

[This](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/closing-old-question-as-duplicate-of-a-new-one) would answer my question, if only it *had* a real, accepted, useful answer, which is why I ask.

---

I encountered [this item](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/close/27449) in the VTC Review Queue. Essentially, it's a case of [a question from 2011](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2323/look-and-say-sequence) being closed as a dupe of [one asked yesterday](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70837/say-what-you-see).

I understand *why* this has happened. Indeed, there are plenty closey votes on the old Q, and it's probably for the best, but I wonder if we have a policy on this.

I don't intend to challenge Mego or the close-voters by asking this question here. I intend to understand more clearly under which circumstances this sort of retro duplicate identification is good or common.

This question pair I cite in particular does have [a discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8281/duplicates-with-different-restrictions-or-no-restrictions), which is helpful to me, but I want to know about the broader scope of *all questions*, not only a restrictions-differences-semantics centered discussion.

When is it appropriate to close an old question of a dupe as a newer one?

I don't believe the two questions are duplicates really, because I think that their separation of intent and time is enough. (This is not reflected by my vote to close, which I cast when I had a different opinion about this 20 minutes ago.)

Comment: Watch this be closed as a dupe because I have failed to convey my misunderstanding :(

Comment: This is absolutely a dupe of the linked discussion. If there's not a clear consensus, either a) write your own answer, b) try to bring attention to the lack of consensus in other ways, or c) accept that it will be judged on a case-by-case basis.